# Typescript: Partial not working in generic type

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

Partial throws an error when I have no valid property, but don't throws an error when I have at least one valid property. Why? "a" is not a valid property of User, so why I don't get an error in the first save call? Is my generic type wrong?

```
interface User {
    firstname: string;
}

function save<T extends Partial<User>>(entity: T) {

}

// no error
save({
    firstname: 'John',
    a: 1,
})

// error
save({
    a: 1,
})

// error
let user: Partial<User> = {
    firstname: 'John',
    a: 1,
}
```

Comment: are you planning to use this generic type in some way? If not, this works as expected: https://tsplay.dev/m3311m

Comment: Yep since it's a generic parameter, excess property checks are a little funky.

Comment: Yes want to use it in a generic way in a class.

Comment: @PeterFox `T extends Partial<User>` means that `T` could be any type that extends `Partial<User>`, so a type with extra properties is (which will be a subtype of `Partial<User>`) is perfectly acceptable. Do you want to capture `T` but make it have at most the properties of `User` ?

Comment: A solution fi my above assumption is right is to capture the specified keys in the type argument instead of the actual object type: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgKoGdrIN4FgBQyRyMwU6YIcAthAFzIVSgDmA3AccgDZwVW0GTVh3wBfAgRgBXEAjDAA9iEZwAbhAA8AFWQQAHpBAATdMgDWEAJ6KYaTFAB8ACgjhgYKwwAKwBOc0MaAAaZG1HZAAyZG84KAU4bkCHRwBKHElxTPR1CGc8QmJSckoaemQAIgrgzmJefjKGKoIxVIIAenbkEEU9KChFKAIcjXzaomKGwWQAcgApRQALEBmawqI4BgBGNdbMzr6BofwRvIKuTeQdlrb8Dq7oI4JuCDBkaQcfOISkoKdkAC8GXWJDIU3K8yWKzWF22uyAA